# execute function when device is offline for long than 10 minutes

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, automation

Hi i wanna execute i a function when my phone is not pingable for 10 minutes

Here is my current code i use to ping my device:

```
ip = "192.168.1.187"

def ping(host):

    param = '-n' if platform.system().lower()=='windows' else '-c'

    command = ['ping', param, '1', host]

    if subprocess.call(command) == 0:
        print("Host is up")#executes function when host is up
        wifi_connected()
        
    else:
        print("Host is down")
        #here it should check if the device is longer than 10 minutes offline and execute a different function

ping(ip)
```

Comment: My iphone is not pingable when I do not use it, even when it is online.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two solutions depending on what you want.

Firstly, if you want to execute ONLY if the device has been offline for all of 10 minutes. You will have to ping the device continuously  by putting this in a loop and reset timer everytime it comes on.Comparing earliest downtime timestamp should work.

OR

You can get timestamp for the first instant it goes offline and check with 10 minute time delay using

```
time.sleep(600)
```

if it still off , execute code

Depends on your requirement.